# Proving $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}\binom{n-j}{i}\ =\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}\binom{n-j}{i}\ =\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k} $$

This one I have no idea how to crack.

Induction doesn't seem to be a sensible idea, I have a list of over 20 binomial identities worth to know in math olympiads, but none of them allow to somehow simplify the product I have here. I tried to find a Vandermonde-type sum here (for many hours), but couldn't remove the sumation indices from the top of binomial.

Comment: This seems to be a case of double counting. You could try to find a combinatorial description of the left-hand-side and the right-and-side that matches.

Comment: @Cornman Does your comment mean that you solved the problem by finding a combinatorial interpretation? Or are you just handing out generic advice?

Comment: @user14111 No, I have never tried, but it would be my first guess for a fitting method of solving this problem, so it is a general advice thats why it is a comment. I just looked into a book on problem solving. There I find a problem: Solve through combinatorial interpretation and "double counting" $\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^i\sum_{k=0}^j \binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{j}\binom{j}{k}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following standard identities are used in the answer:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x} &= \sum\limits_n x^n, \\
(x+y)^s &= \sum\limits_{i+j=s} \binom{i+j}{i} x^i y^j, \\
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} &= \sum\limits_n \binom{n+k}{k} x^n.
\end{align}$$

To allow a better separation, let's say that we're given $n$ and $m$, and want to find
$$
\sum\limits_{i,j} \binom{i+j}{i} \binom{n-i}{j} \binom{m-j}{i}.
$$
This allows us to assume that $i$ and $j$ are fixed, and find the bivariate generating function

$$
\binom{i+j}{i}\sum\limits_{n=i}^\infty \binom{n-i}{j} x^n \sum\limits_{m=j}^\infty \binom{m-j}{i} y^m.
$$
Let's find the genfunc of individual sums via $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum\limits_n \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=i}^\infty \binom{n-i}{j} x^n = \frac{x^{i+j}}{(1-x)^{j+1}},
$$
thus the full bivariate genfunc of the sum is
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \binom{i+j}{i} \frac{x^{i+j}}{(1-x)^{j+1}}\frac{y^{i+j}}{(1-y)^{i+1}}.
$$
Using $s=i+j$, we rewrite the sum via $\sum\limits_{i+j=s} \binom{i+j}{i} x^i y^j = (x+y)^s$ and $\sum\limits_s x^s = \frac{1}{1-x}$ as
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-y} \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \left(\frac{xy}{1-x}+\frac{xy}{1-y}\right)^s = \frac{1}{(1-xy)(1-x-y)}.
$$

What remains now is to find
$$\begin{align}
[x^n y^n]\frac{1}{(1-xy)(1-x-y)} &= [x^n y^n]\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k y^k \frac{1}{1-x-y} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n [x^k y^k] \frac{1}{1-x-y} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n [x^k y^k](x+y)^{2k} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}. \square
\end{align}$$

P.S. It also shows that we can evaluate the sum for any $(n, m)$ as

$$\sum\limits_{i,j} \binom{i+j}{i} \binom{n-i}{j} \binom{m-j}{i} = \sum\limits_{k} \binom{n+m-2k}{n-k}.
$$

Comment: I personally can not follow many of your calculations, but I was never confronted with generating functions. For example why does $\sum_{n=i}^\infty \binom{n-i}{j}x^n=\frac{x^{i+j}}{(1-x)^{j+1}}$ hold? Not critisism but you mostly state unmotivated equations. (At least for me, but as I said I am not really familiar with these type of questions, and would like to learn from your answer, which I can not, so maybe you take this as an oppertunity to rewrite your answer? I would highly appreciate it. <3)

Comment: There is a standard expansion $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum\limits_n \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$$ that follows from the binomial theorem with negative powers. The sum that you are referring to is a consequence of it, as with the substitution $m=n-i-j$ it rewrites into $$\sum\limits_n \binom{n-i}{j} x^n = \sum\limits_{m} \binom{m+j}{j}x^{m+i+j} = x^{i+j} \sum\limits_m \binom{m+j}{j} x^m = \frac{x^{i+j}}{(1-x)^{j+1}}.$$

Comment: @Cornman To add on to Oleksandr's comment: if you know that $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$, you can differentiate this $k$ times to get $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$. The factors coming from the power rule combine to give the binomial coefficient on the righthand side.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! @OleksandrKulkov Your edit helps the readability for novices a lot, as far as a novice can judge! Thanks for your effort.